# module: command not found

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, environment-modules

I'm attempting to load several modules for building a library on Linux but am told that the command 'module' doesn't exist. I've Googled around and discovered that the solution was to source a directory called "module" which I am unable to locate despite extensive searching.

I'm not quite sure what I should and any help would be appreciated (it might help to know that the makefile I'm working with uses csh while my default shell is bash). Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code samples, maybe part of your Makefile. And any error message you're getting

Comment: can you try running 'which module', may be the $PATH doesn't have the command/script called module

Comment: Specifying what library you're trying to build would also be potentially helpful.

Answer (score 27):

I tried to reproduce it and it turns out that for me sourcing

```
source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
```

in th `.sh` script helps for `bash` and similar. For `csh` and `tcsh`, you have to add

```
source /etc/profile.d/modules.csh
```

to the script. Note, that this line must come first and then the

```
module load foo
```

line.

Comment: Note `.` is probably preferred over `source` since it complies with POSIX. (I have run into trouble before with `source` not working in all contexts.)

Answer (score 5):

I got here as I was searching for ways to install multiple php versions in CentOS7 and https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2019/05/22/PHP-7.4-as-Software-Collection was one of the articles I tried to follow and encountered the same "module: command not found" issue.

Sourcing /etc/profile via command:

`. /etc/profile`

seems to make the "module load" work.

Credits to fadishei in https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?262708-module-command-not-found

To make the version of php (e.g. php7.4) persist, append the following to file `/etc/profile.d/custom.sh`

```
source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
module load php74
```

Reboot and run the `php --version` to cross-check that php 7.4 is the current version installed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using `zsh` instead of the default `bash` shell.

After switching to `bash` and submitting the script, it worked out

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to put this in your script to define the module command:

```
module () {
    eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was working for me

```
#!/bin/bash -i // it will make this interactive
```

Comment: This is dangerous, it can hide the real problem.